# How to implement multiple plan in rails with stripe checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement multiple plan subscription on a rails app with stripe.

My subscription controller

```
def new
    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      client_reference_id: current_user.id,
      customer_email: current_user.email,
      subscription_data: {
        items: [{
          plan: 'beginner'
        }]
      },
      success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    )
    @session_id = session.id
  end
```

My Routes

```
....
resources :subscriptions, only: :new
....
```

My subscription button is like

```
<%= link_to 'Subscribe to Beginner', new_subscription_path,  %>
<%= link_to 'Subscribe to Pro', #TODO,  %>
```

With this setup, I can subscribe to the beginner plan with no issue.

My question is how to add a pro plan to this setup. What will the routes look like?

I have all the plans created in my stripe dashboard.
I have checked the docs but it is not clear for me.

I have seen you can pass params in the link like so

```
<%= link_to "subscribe", some_path(:params[:value]) %>
```

How can I achieve that kind of URL?

And after all, I want to have a method on the user model to check if the user is subscribed to the beginner or pro

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looks like you're asking about "query parameters".**

You can add params to the URL

```
<%= link_to 'Subscribe to Beginner', new_subscription_path(plan: :beginner),  %>
<%= link_to 'Subscribe to Pro', new_subscription_path(plan: :pro),  %>
```

`new_subscription_path(plan: :beginner)` will evaluate to `subscription/new?plan=beginner`

Then you can access this in the model via params.

```
  def new
    plan_type = params[:plan]

    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      client_reference_id: current_user.id,
      customer_email: current_user.email,
      subscription_data: {
        items: [{
          plan: plan_type
        }]
      },
      success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    )
    @session_id = session.id
  end
```

Comment: That's great thanks for the answer it works. My next challenge is to create a method probable on the user model to scope users base on their subscription type. I am thinking of something like ```def pro_user  and user_starter```